# Error de sintaxis #1064 al crear un procedimiento almacenado con un cursor en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Buenas soy nuevo en esto de PL/SQL. intento realizar un procedimiento almacenado desde phpmyadmin en el panel sql y obtengo un error de sintaxis al ejecutarlo y dice: **#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'AS CURSOR ventas_clientes_cursor IS SELECT FROM venta WHERE venta.id_c...' en la linea 2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ventas_usuario(CLIENTE_ID VARCHAR(9))
    AS CURSOR ventas_clientes_cursor IS
    SELECT * FROM venta WHERE venta.id_cliente = CLIENTE_ID;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ventas del usuario cliente: 'CLIENTE_ID);
    FOR ventas IN ventas_clientes_cursor LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fecha de la venta: 'ventas.fecha);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Precio de la venta: 'ventas.precio);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('--------------------------------------');
    END LOOP
END;
```

Alguna solucion ?

Comment: ¿Seguro que esto es en MySQL?

Comment: MySQL no soporta PL/SQL, que es el _dialecto_ de Oracle. Por tanto, no intentes utilizar la sintaxis de PL/SQL en MySQL, debes aprender la sintaxis de dicho motor para realizar la tarea que quieres.